# Two canonical constructions for a scheme map $\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(x) \to X$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme and $x \in X$. Then there is a canonical scheme morphism $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_{X,x} \to X$ (Vakil’s Exercise 6.3.J(a)) and the quotient map $\mathcal O_{X,x} \to \kappa(x)$ induces a map between their spectra. Then composition gives a canonical scheme morphism $\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(x) \to X$.

However, there is also a more explicit way for a canonical morphism. Namely, we define $(\pi,\alpha): \operatorname{Spec} \kappa(x) \to X$ as follows. As a continuous function, $\pi$ sends the unique point of the spectrum to the point $x$. (I mean, what else can you do?) Then for every open subset $U$ of $X$, if $x \not\in U$, then $\alpha_U$ is the unique map to the zero ring. If $x \in U$, then $\alpha_U$ is the composition
$$\mathcal O_X(U) \to \mathcal O_{X,x} \to \kappa(x)$$
where the second map is the quotient map. So there is a few naturally-arising questions.

1. $(\pi,\alpha)$ defines a morphism of ringed spaces, but does it defines a scheme morphism? (I honestly have no idea on showing the induced map on stalks is local.)
2. If it is a scheme morphism, then is it the same as the one obtained in the first paragraph? (It should, as they are both “canonical”)
3. Assuming question 2 (i.e. $\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(x) \to X$ factors through $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_{X,x} \to X$), is there a choice-free description of the scheme morphism $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_{X,x} \to X$. (I mean, the map is choice-free, but can we define it without choosing an open affine in the first place?)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. is easy since you only need to check the condition for the unique point in $\operatorname{Spec}\kappa(x)$, in which case the map on local rings is given by the quotient map $\mathcal O_{X,x}\to \kappa(x)$.
2. yes, both maps are the same.
3. We can write $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_{X,x}$ as the limit over all open subschemes of $X$ that contain $x$. Then the map into $X$ is just the one induced by the inclusions of the open subschemes into $X$.